# Find the functions $F$ such that $\sin(F(x))$ can be simplified

Tags: trigonometry

There are some obvious functions $F$ such that $\sin(F(x))$ can be simplified, for example $ax + b$ for any $a, b$, $\sin^{-1}(x)$ up to periodicity, etc. Is it possible to find all the functions for which simplification is possible, by which I suppose I mean the function can be rewritten in terms of elementary functions without infinite series and without the expression $\sin(F(x))$ itself appearing anywhere?

Comment: how is $sin(ax+b)$ simplified? Would you consider applying $$sin(x+y)=sin(x)cos(y)+sin(y)cos(x)$$ on $sin(F(x)-b+b)$ a simplification?